# getting error Authentication credentials were not provided in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Hi Everyone i am creating login api in DRF and getting response also as i expected but i test token to other api then got error **Authentication credentials were not provided,**  i don't know where i am going wrong please help me out.also custom user model can't possible to use because that model i have already used

**setting.py-** this is setting file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'api.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework_datatables.renderers.DatatablesRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework_datatables.filters.DatatablesFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework_datatables.pagination.DatatablesPageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,
}
```

**models.py**

```
class GmsUser(GmsBaseModel):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "gms_users"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def gms_user_login(request):
    user_name = request.data.get("user_name")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    users=GmsUser.objects.filter(user_name=user_name).values_list('id',flat=True)
    role=GmsRole.objects.filter(id=GmsUserRole.objects.filter(user=users[0]).values_list('role',flat=True)[0]).values_list('role',flat=True)[0]
    # city=GmsUserProfile.objects.filter(user=users[0]).values_list('city',flat=True)[0]
    try:
        query=GmsUserRole.objects.filter(user=users[0]).exists()
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({"message":"User not found","error":True,"code":400,"results":str(e)},status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    if user_name is None or password is None:
        return Response({'detail': 'Please provide both username and password'})
    else:
        try:
            if query:
                user = GmsUser.objects.get(user_name=user_name)
        except GmsUser.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'detail': 'Invalid UserName'})
        if user.password.lower() != password.lower():
            return Response({'detail': 'Invalid Password'})
    user.token=get_random_string(length=50)
    user.save()
    response_data=GmsUserSignupSerializer(user).data
    response_data1=GmsRoleSerializer(GmsRole.objects.get(role=role)).data
    response_data2=GmsUserProfileSerializer(GmsUserProfile.objects.get(user=users[0])).data
    response_data['roles']=response_data1
    response_data['user_profile']=response_data2
    try:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "login","error":False,"code":200,"results":{'token':user.token,'user':response_data}},status=HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "login","error":True,"code":500,"results":str(e)},status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Login api Response**

```
{
    "message": "login",
    "error": false,
    "code": 200,
    "results": {
        "token": "7R1EAR6qQdTyM6ZvD7kHfwdCHoj33tsp1QXUCIXSqU8929uMOq",
        "user": {
            "id": 4,
            "user_name": "edwin",
            "password": "1234"
            "roles": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "user_profile": {
                "id": 2
                "city": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think api.authentication.TokenAuthentication is wrong. Please show the code.

Comment: You must be using `api.authentication.TokenAuthentication`. But I recommend using builtin system provided by rest framwork package. Maybe I can add the code for using `rest_framework.authtoken`. Do you want me to do that?

Comment: @MukhtorRasulov i have shared already code? which code u want?

Comment: How did you use the token on the other APIs? Can you update your question with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the right `authentication` class to be used in settings.py.
Now there are 4 classes defined. But I think you have to set one class.

If you select the `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication`, you don't need to create token with random string. The `rest_framework.authtoken` app will create `Token` model and you can just use that.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'api.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    ),
    ...
}
```

Comment: its possible to use Token model  multiple time because i used already another login api, i have change setting.py file but its work for me

Comment: no its not work for me.

Comment: How can I help you further?

Comment: i can try to solve this diffirent way but got error here i have post the que. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72367290/getting-wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-data-error-in-drf-login-api

Comment: gettting [WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data] while hit login api at postman with user_name & password